# Not able to access Google Compute Engine VM - All of a sudden

Tags: timeout, google-compute-engine

- I am not able to ping my VM with public IP
- Also not able to SSH even from GCP web
- I tried creating new SSH key even, but what ever I do SSH connection is timeout
- Also ping is getting timeout

But the VM seems to be running properly while I check on GCP compute engine

Tried Creating new SSH key for connecting, seems like VM isn't allowing 22 port

Comment: Did you change anything on the firewall side?

Comment: Compute Engine supports two types of public IP addresses. Ephemeral and reserved (static). Which type of IP address is your instance using? Most likely your VM is using an ephemeral address that can change during instance restart. Another possibility is your instance has hung or crashed. Try rebooting. Also, look in the Cloud logs for your instance for problems. Edit your question with more details once you review those items.

Comment: I have reserved a static IP for my VM and I am sure my IP won't change. Also haven't touched the VM firewall side for a while mostly like few months. Also I don't remember when I lastly SSH to this VM as well

Comment: Closing this ticket, Found the solutions it was due to my VM having very low disk space. Due to this low disk space the booting of VM didn't happen properly. And its worth checking boot size of your VMs if any one of you face same issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Closing this ticket, Found the solutions it was due to my VM having very low disk space. Due to this low disk space the booting of VM didn't happen properly. And its worth checking boot size of your VMs if any one of you face same issue. Thanks